# How to extend CMssqlCommandBuilder and use extended class in model

Tags: yii

I am using `YII` with `MSSQL`

There was a problem with `CMssqlCommandBuilder` when trying to use pagination.
I used the code given in `comment#7` at http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=1501

I edited the `CMssqlCommandBuilder` and my code just worked fine.

Now the problem is I don't want to change `Yii`'s `CMssqlCommandBuilder` class I want to extend a class from `CMssqlCommandBuilder` and use that class instead.

How can I tell my model classes to use new extended class instead of `CMssqlCommandBuilder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite the `getCommandBuilder()` in a base model class extending CActiveRecord.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#getCommandBuilder-detail

```
class MyActiveRecord extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function getCommandBuilder()
    {
        return new MyMssqlCommandBuilder($this->getDbConnection()->getSchema());
    }
}
```

Not sure if it is "the right way" to do it though.

I might be more appropriate to do the following:

```
class MyActiveRecord extends CActiveRecord
{
    private $_builder;
    public function getCommandBuilder()
    {
        if($this->_builder!==null)
            return $this->_builder;
        else
            return $this->_builder = new MyMssqlCommandBuilder($this->getDbConnection()->getSchema());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post @jborch. it did the job.